# How do I use my own domain for my own openID login without having to make a myopenid domain account?

Tags: openid

I have my own domain signed-up under myOpenID as follows:

```
openid.mysite.com
```

Everything is verified and seems to be working properly on the myOpenID site.  However, now I want to setup my website so I only have to enter the domain name as my openID login.

I have read https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/ and understand the basic concept using header link tags.  However, instead of...

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://username.myopenid.com/">
```

I want to use my own site for the openid.delegate as follows...

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://openid.example.com/username" />
```

And this works on my site with no problems!  However, I only plan to have one user authenticated through my site, me.  I do not plan on having any other users, so I would simply like to have...

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://openid.example.com" />
```

...note the lack of username in the openid.delegate href.  I want to do this not only for a shorter link href, but also so I don't have to make a domain account on myopenid.com, adding yet another login, etc.

Does that make sense?  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openid.delegate` is an op-local identifier, i.e. the `username.myopenid.com` one. It has *nothing* to do with your website url.

Example:
I authenticate using `http://example.com/` as OpenID identifier.
On `example.com`, there is a html file that contains:

```
<link rel="openid.server openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid.delegate openid2.local_id" href="http://username.myopenid.com/">
```

And... it works. I don't know what else could be your problem here. The "openid2" parts of `rel` attribute allow to use OpenID2 instead of 1.0 (and can be used only if the provider supports OpenID 2.0, and myopenid.com does).
My OpenID as seen by the relying party would be "http://example.com/", and if I understand correctly, it's what you want.

However, if you wanted to use `select_identifier`, i.e. select a login at the provider's site, it's not possible to delegate that (and it doesn't make sense anyway).